# How do I create this scrolling effect?

Tags: javascript, css

I've been starring at this for a while, and tried different approaches, such as using position: sticky combined with intersection observer, but cant quite wrap my head around it :(

So I wanted to ask if anyone knows how to do this scrolling effect? Can it be done with CSS only, or with the intersection observer? If so, can anyone point me in a direction on how to do it?  Maybe a library or a Codepen that can help ? Havent quite been able to find anything?

*Scrolling Effect*:

[image: Scrolling Effect]

Comment: This Scroll Effects can be done using GSAP and ScrollMagic library.
<br />
[Example Link to scroll effect][1]
<br/>
[Github link to source code][2]


  [1]: https://ferin79.github.io/Portfolio/
  [2]: https://github.com/Ferin79/Portfolio

Comment: @FerinPatel for anchors use this template [ display text goes here ]( link goes here )

Comment: Why are there three upvotes for this? I see no code, no effort to actually do anything other than beg for someone else to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved it using intersectionObserver and CSS

```
const texts = document.querySelectorAll('.text h1');

  const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      const entryParentNode = entry.target.parentNode;
      const initialImage = entryParentNode.getAttribute('data-image');
      const images = document.querySelectorAll('.image');
      if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
        entryParentNode.classList.add('show');
        images.forEach((image) => {
          if (image.classList.contains(initialImage)) {
            image.classList.add('show');
          } else {
            image.classList.add('hide');
          }
        })
      } else {
        entryParentNode.classList.toggle('hide');
        images.forEach((image) => {
          if (image.classList.contains(initialImage)) {
            image.classList.remove('show');
          } else {
            image.classList.add('hide');
          }
        })
      }
    });
  });
  texts.forEach((text) => {
    observer.observe(text);
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my try at it. Using CSS and JavaScript.

The menu bar has `position: fixed` 
The phone block has `position: sticky` with `margin-top: 100vh` 
The p elements have a `margin: 100vh` between each other.
And you'll find the explanations about the JavaScript directly in the comments in the script.
I used the [scrollTop](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_scrolltop.asp) and [offsetTop](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_offsettop.asp) properties.

Use the full page view to see it better!

```js
<script>
  function scrollFunction() {
  // Array of all the p elements inside #content
  var p = document.getElementById('content').querySelectorAll('p')

  // Storing the offsetTop positions of those p element
  var pY = []
  for (i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    pY[i] = p[i].offsetTop
  }

  // browserScroll -> the scrolling position on the screen for usual Firefox, Chrome etc.
  var html = document.documentElement
  var browserScroll = html.scrollTop

  // safariScroll -> the scrolling position for Safari
  var body = document.body;
  var safariScroll = html.scrollTop

  // Getting the phone element
  var phone = document.getElementById('phone')


  // When the scrolling value is greater than the Y coordinate of each p element writes the corresponding class for each p element
  // .color1 for 1st paragraph and so on...
  // (minus pY[0]*0.4) is here to have the change happening when p is aligned with the top of the phone
  for (i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    if (browserScroll > pY[i] - pY[0] * 0.4 ||
      safariScroll > pY[i] - pY[0] * 0.4) {
      phone.classList.add('color' + (i + 1))
      phone.classList.remove('color' + i)
    } else {
      phone.classList.remove('color' + (i + 1))
    }
  }
}

window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()}
window.onresize = function() {scrollFunction()}

</script>
```

```css
body {
  background: white;
  color: #323232;
  font-weight: 300;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica neue, roboto;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -6px 25px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.44);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px -6px 25px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.44);
  box-shadow: 0px -6px 25px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.44);
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

nav ul li {
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

#content {
  width: 50%;
}

/* The first paragraph has a margin-top = the size of the screen*/
#content:first-child {
  margin-top: 100vh;
}

#content p {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 100vh;
}

/* Same margin-top as the 1st paragraph + sticky at 40% from the top*/
#phone {
  margin-top: 100vh;
  width: 8rem;
  height: 13rem;
  max-height: 70vh;
  position: sticky;
  top: 40%;
  background: lightgreen;
}

#phone.color1 {
  background: palevioletred;
}

#phone.color2 {
  background: purple;
}

#phone.color3 {
  background: royalblue;
}

#phone.color4 {
  background: rgb(30, 150, 104);
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Menu</li>
    <li>Bar</li>
    <li>Scrolling</li>
    <li>Effect</li>

  </ul>
</nav>
<main>
  <div id="content">
    <p>
      One advanced diverted domestic fox repeated bringing you old. Possible procured her trifling laughter thoughts property she met way.
    </p>
    <p>
      Finished her are its honoured drawings nor. Pretty see mutual thrown all not edward ten. Particular an boisterous up he reasonably frequently.
    </p>
    <p>
      May musical arrival beloved luckily adapted him. Shyness mention married son she his started now. Rose if as past near were. To graceful he elegance oh moderate attended entrance pleasur
    </p>
    <p>
      Out believe has request not how comfort evident. Up delight cousins we feeling minutes.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="phone">
  </div>
</main
```

Comment: If your answer involves code, it should be in your question. Not on a third party site.

Comment: I guess this was meant for the question not this answer

Comment: No, it was meant for you

Comment: So you meant if my answer involves code, it should be in my answer (not question)?
And I shouldn't put the link to a JSFiddle ? If so, sorry I didn't know.
So I should write the whole html, css, and javascript in my answer?

Comment: Any relevant code should be in the both question and answer, not only accessible on a third party site like jsFiddle. Not my rule, SO's rule. Also, questions and answers have a built in function for you to add an executable example just like jsFiddle does

Comment: @tamarin, what he is trying to say is that you should put all of your code here in your answer in CODE brackets and then after that you can say Fiddle: myfidlelink.com :) Your solution is great!

Comment: @AleksandarĐokić Not really. There's no need for jsFiddle here at all. You can embed a runnable example in any question or answer via the built-in snippet feature.

Comment: Ok thank you for your advices. I'm new here.
Removed the JSFiddle and put the code in my answer.